# Transfering from github pages to cloudfare pages

Tags: wordpress, jekyll, github-pages, cloudflare-pages

So I'm a brand new guy on this web-building stuff. i have a page on GitHub page that I generated from a Wordpress instalation exported to static files through a plugin. they are all static files. but when i try to use this same repository on cloudfare pages (i select the jerkyl framework because thats what i understand github uses) i get a build error

```
21:47:34.423    Success: Finished cloning repository files
21:47:34.697    Installing dependencies
21:47:34.710    Python version set to 2.7
21:47:38.959    v12.18.0 is already installed.
21:47:40.464    Now using node v12.18.0 (npm v6.14.4)
21:47:40.845    Started restoring cached build plugins
21:47:40.864    Finished restoring cached build plugins
21:47:41.647    Attempting ruby version 2.7.1, read from environment
21:47:48.133    Using ruby version 2.7.1
21:47:48.547    Using PHP version 5.6
21:47:48.733    5.2 is already installed.
21:47:48.766    Using Swift version 5.2
21:47:48.766    Installing Hugo 0.54.0
21:47:49.458    Hugo Static Site Generator v0.54.0-B1A82C61A/extended linux/amd64 BuildDate: 2019-02-01T10:04:38Z
21:47:49.463    Started restoring cached go cache
21:47:49.488    Finished restoring cached go cache
21:47:49.664    go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
21:47:49.687    go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
21:47:49.691    Installing missing commands
21:47:49.692    Verify run directory
21:47:49.692    Executing user command: jekyll build
21:47:49.699    /opt/build/bin/build: line 39: jekyll: command not found
21:47:49.707    Failed: build command exited with code: 127
```

am i missing something? am i supposed to use another framework?